# Hiding Types from Autoquery Metadata

Tags: metadata, servicestack, rdbms, ormlite-servicestack

I have an RDBMS AutoQuery setup with Custom QueryDb object which is the only object I wish to be exposed by Autoquery metadata, however, it is exposing all my ORMLite data objects to the UI. Is there an attribute that would hide these objects from the metadata as I want to control what can be queried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the [ServiceStack Admin UI AutoQueryMetadataFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin#advanced-customizations), you can remove Types and Operations in its `MetadataFilter`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryMetadataFeature {
    MaxLimit = ...,
    MetadataFilter = res => {
        res.Operations.RemoveAll(x => ...);
        res.Types.RemoveAll(x => ...);
    }
});
```